# Convert SVG path to Glyph path

Tags: html, svg

I have existing code something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
<font id="actionitems" horiz-adv-x="1024">
<font-face units-per-em="1024" ascent="960" descent="-64" />
<missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="1024" />
<glyph unicode="&#x20;" horiz-adv-x="512" d="" />
<glyph unicode="&#xe900;" glyph-name="glyphicons-halflings-101-exclamation-sign" data-tags="glyphicons-halflings-101-exclamation-sign" d="M554.667 672.939c-135.979 0-246.229-110.251-246.229-246.272s110.251-246.229 246.229-246.229 246.229 110.251 246.229 246.229-110.251 246.272-246.229 246.272zM591.445 404.95c-2.219-11.52-13.653-20.949-25.344-20.949h-22.827c-11.733 0-23.125 9.429-25.344 20.949l-24.704 128.768c-2.261 11.52 5.547 20.949 17.28 20.949h88.32c11.733 0 19.499-9.429 17.323-20.949l-24.704-128.768zM597.333 266.667c0-5.845-4.821-10.667-10.667-10.667h-64c-5.845 0-10.667 4.821-10.667 10.667v64c0 5.845 4.821 10.667 10.667 10.667h64c5.845 0 10.667-4.821 10.667-10.667v-64z" />
<glyph ..... />
<glyph ..... />
...
</font></defs></svg>
```

I want to add an additonal `<glyph>` element here so that my existing solution will read the unicode Id and render the svg. How can I achieve that for the following SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 192 192"><path d="M156 72.1h-17.1l8.6-15-7-4-10.8 19h-26.8l13.4-23.2 21.9.1v-8l-17.3-.1 8.6-14.8-7-4-8.5 14.8-8.7-14.9-6.9 4 11 18.9L96 68.1 82.6 44.9l11-18.9-6.9-4L78 36.9l-8.5-14.8-7 4 8.6 14.8-17.3.1v8l21.9-.1 13.4 23.2H62.3l-10.8-19-7 4 8.6 15H36v8h17.1l-8.6 15 7 4 10.8-19h26.8l-13.4 23.1-21.9-.1v8l17.3.1-8.6 14.8 7 4 8.5-14.8 8.7 15 6.9-4.1-11-18.9L96 84.1l13.4 23.1-11 18.9 6.9 4.1 8.7-15 8.5 14.8 7-4-8.6-14.8 17.3-.1v-8l-21.9.1-13.4-23.1h26.8l10.8 19 7-4-8.6-15H156zM132 176c-16.9 0-27.5-5.3-37.8-10.4C84.3 160.7 75 156 60 156c-22 0-37 14.7-37.2 14.8l-5.7-5.7c.8-.6 17.5-17.1 42.9-17.1 16.9 0 27.5 5.3 37.8 10.4 9.9 4.9 19.2 9.6 34.2 9.6 22 0 37-14.7 37.2-14.8l5.7 5.7c-.8.6-17.5 17.1-42.9 17.1z"/></svg>
```

Copy pasting the `d` attribute of path renders an empty square

[image]

Comment: No browser supports glyphs directly so there must be some processing going on here. Invoke that for your new glyph, whatever it is. Not also that while glyph and path d have the same syntax but the co-ordinate system is reversed in y.

Comment: @RobertLongson how do I reverse the coordinate system?

Comment: apply a scale transform e.g. scale (1, -1). You might need a translate too.